# Using ASP.NET Identity with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have researched Google and this site extensively, and cannot find an answer. I'm trying to add ASP.NET Identity to Visual Studio, and I've been working off of [this page](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project).

The problem is, everything from that article is in C#, and my project is specifically in Visual Basic (ASP.NET Framework 4.5.1, *not* MVC). Also, I'm too new to web dev to know exactly what to change. I found a C# to VB converter, and it worked for the most part but I'm still missing something since I get errors within VS. I'm not even 100% sure I can get Identity to work in VB instead of C#, though I don't see why not.

I'm trying to keep this as concise as possible, so I'll denote the issues in **bold**.

This is the register.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebFormsIdentity.Register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h4 style="font-size: medium">Register a new user</h4>
        <hr />
        <p>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="StatusMessage" />
        </p>                
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</asp:Label>
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" />                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

No errors in VB, but upon after running the page I get a 'Parser Error' in the browser: "**Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebFormsIdentity.Register**'."

This is the code behind; the majority of the issues are with this page:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Linq

Namespace WebFormsIdentity
    Partial Public Class Register
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            ' Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
            Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
            Dim manager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)

            Dim user = New IdentityUser() With { _
                Key .UserName = UserName.Text _
            }
            Dim result As IdentityResult = manager.Create(user, Password.Text)

            If result.Succeeded Then
                StatusMessage.Text = String.Format("User {0} was created successfully!", user.UserName)
            Else
                StatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**On the line under 'Dim user', the word 'Key' has this error:**

> Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

**On the line with 'Dim result', the word 'Password' has this:**

> 'Password' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

**On the line under 'result.Succeeded', the word 'StatusMessage' has this:**

> 'StatusMessage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

**And finally, same line, 'user.UserName' has this:**

> 'UserName' is not a member of 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.

I've only been using VB for about six weeks, so I'm a baby dev. I do know how to declare things, but I don't understand why the author of the above link didn't have to do anything extra in his code, except that it is C#.

Anyway, thanks for reading and for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue. Steps:

1) Completely uninstalled VS 2013 Premium 
2) Installed VS 2013 Ultimate 
 
3) When starting a new project, instead of using an empty template I chose 'Web Forms' with the default 'Individual User Account' Authentication.
4) From the NuGet packages, installed ['Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.2.1)

Running the application then worked properly; I was able to register a user without any errors.

For future reference, the correct code was as follows. Notice that 'Owin' references had to be imported.

**Register.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebFormsIdentity.Register" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="WebFormsIdentity" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <p class="text-danger">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
    </p>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create a new account</h4>
        <hr />
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm password</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                    CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The confirm password field is required." />
                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                    CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password and confirmation password do not match." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Register.aspx.vb:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Register
    Inherits Page
    Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim userName As String = Email.Text
        Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
        Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
        Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName, .Email = userName}
        Dim result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text)
        If result.Succeeded Then
            ' For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            ' Dim code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)
            ' Dim callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request)
            ' manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>.")

            signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent := False, rememberBrowser := False)
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
        Else
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

OK.
First remove word "KEY" - it's came from Telerik convertor - I do not know the reason.
Second. On your HTML code duplicate ID=UserName and ID=Password win name="UserName" and name="Password"
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: If I could 'upvote' your answer, I would. The 'key' reference was definitely an issue. Thanks for helping!